# Is it possible to set a Pathview element in QML to stop when it reaches last element in the model?

Tags: qml

Pathview rotate to the first element when it reaches end, how to stop it when it reaches the end?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "grey"
    opacity: 1
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: delegate
            Text {
                id: nameText
                width: 64; height: 20
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                text: name
            }

    }
    Rectangle {
        y:parent.height/2
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height/2
        ListView {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            model:  listModel

            focus: true
            delegate: Text {
                      id: item
                      text: name + ": " + number
                  }
            preferredHighlightBegin: 20
            preferredHighlightEnd: 40
            highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
            highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightblue"; radius:  5 }
        }
    }
}
```

This effect can be achieved by ListView, with the properties setting.

Comment: this is not answer in my opinion. PathView has unique utilisations that ListView has not. So this answer is out of area of the question.